A lower bound for a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^2$
Let $a, c > 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$,
\begin{equation*}
a x^2 - 2bxy + cy^2 \ge \frac{ac - b^2}{2}\min(a^{-1}, c^{-1}) (x^2 + y^2).
\end{equation*}
This lower bound is asserted on page 1842 of the article Banks-Kojima 2002 (appearing in the journal Inverse Problems). It is stated that the proof of the inequality is elementary but no proof is given.
For starters let us consider the case when $a  = c$. Then we need to show
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a^2}{2} x^2 - 2abxy + \frac{a^2}{2}y^2 \ge -\frac{b^2}{2} (x^2 + y^2),
\end{equation*}
which follows immediately from applying Young's inequality a few times,
\begin{equation*}
|2abxy| \le (\frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{b^2}{2}) 2|xy| \le  (\frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{b^2}{2})(x^2 + y^2).
\end{equation*}
The case $a \neq c$ seems more difficult. For instance, if $a \ge c$, we need to see that
\begin{equation*}
a^2 x^2 - 2abxy + cay^2 + \frac{b^2}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \ge \frac{ac}{2} (x^2 + y^2).
\end{equation*}
It is no longer clear to me how to go about bounding $|2abxy|$.
Edit: From an answer below and its comments, it is clear that the estimate holds if $ac - b^2 \ge 0$, but can fail in certain situations where $ac - b^2 < 0$.

Part 1: If $ac-b^2 \ge 0$ then the inequality holds for all $(x, y)\in \Bbb R^2$, and there is a short proof:
By “completing the square” one gets
$$
 Q(x, y) = ax^2 - 2bxy + c y^2 
= a \left( x - \frac ba y\right)^2 + \frac{ac-b^2}{a}y^2 
$$
and it follows that
$$ 
Q(x, y) \ge (ac-b^2 )a^{-1}y^2  \ge (ac-b^2)\min(a^{-1}, c^{-1}) y^2 \, .
$$
In the same way one gets
$$ 
Q(x, y) \ge (ac-b^2 )c^{-1}x^2  \ge (ac-b^2)\min(a^{-1}, c^{-1}) x^2 \, .
$$
Adding these two inequalities gives the desired estimate.

Part 2: Now let use consider the general case and determine under which conditions
$$ \tag{$*$}
a x^2 - 2bxy + cy^2 \ge \frac{ac - b^2}{2}\min(a^{-1}, c^{-1}) (x^2 + y^2)
$$
holds for all $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$. We still assume that $a, c > 0$ and $b \in \Bbb R$, but we make no a-priori assumption on the sign of $ac-b^2$.
Let us temporarily assume that $a \ge c$. Then $(*)$ is
$$
 ax^2 - 2bxy + c y^2 \ge \frac{ac-b^2}{2a}(x^2+y^2)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
 \left( a - \frac{ac-b^2}{2a}\right) x^2 - 2bxy + \left(c - \frac{ac-b^2}{2a} \right) y^2 \ge 0 \\
\iff (2a^2-ac+b^2) x^2 - 4abxy + (ac+b^2) y^2 \ge 0 
$$
This holds for all $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$ if and only of the quadratic polynomial
$$
 p(u) = (ac+b^2) u^2 - 4ab u + (2a^2-ac+b^2)
$$
satisfies $p(u) \ge 0$ for all $u$. And since $p$ has a positive leading coefficient this is the case if and only if the discriminant
$$
 \Delta = (4ab)^2 - 4(ac+b^2)(2a^2-ac+b^2)
= 4(b^2-ac)(2a^2-ac-b^2)
$$
is zero or negative.
So we have shown that if $a \ge c$ then $(*)$ holds for all $(x, y)$ if and only if $(ac-b^2)(2a^2-ac-b^2) \ge 0$. Then the general result is:

$(*)$ holds for all $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$ if and only if
$$ \tag{$**$}
(ac-b^2)(2\max(a, c)^2-ac-b^2) \ge 0\, .
 $$

This is surely the case if $ac-b^2 \ge 0$, confirming the result of part 1.
A concrete counterexample: $(a, b, c) = (3, 2, 1)$ does not satisfy the condition $(**)$. Then $p(u) = 7 u^2 - 24 u + 19$ and $p(2) = -1 < 0$, so that $(*)$ does not hold if $y/x = 2$, e.g. for $(x, y) = (1, 2)$. This is also the example given by Will Jagy in a comment.

Martin,  don't delete it. I was planning to leave a comment to the question saying to first separate the cases $ac> b^2,$  then $ac = b^2,$ finally $ac < b^2$  the indefinite case. The positive case is the one I have used over and over, but not this business with the minima.  In my notes, section 3 is pages 4-7 http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jagy_Encyclopedia.pdf

experimenting, $a=c=x=y=1$  and $b > 1$  we really do get $2-2b > 1 - b^2$   with equality at $b = 1$

Thank you for the answer. It does turn out that in the situation I wish to apply this inequality, I will have $ac - b^2 \ge 0$. But do you mean that it fails when $ac < b^2$?

If we take $a = b = 1$, $x  = 1/2$ and $y  =1$, then rearranging the terms we would need $(-1/8)  + (3c/8) \ge 0$, which fails in the limit that $c \to 0^+$.

@JZS: I have updated the answer for the case $ac-b^2 < 0$. As you already noticed, the inequality may fail. A precise condition for the validity of the inequality is now given.

alright, $a=3, b=2, c=1$  after which $x=1, y=2.$  So $3x^2 - 4xy + y^2 = -1.$ But $  \frac{-1}{6}  ( x^2 + y^2) =  \frac{-5}{6}$  which is larger

Hint: The lower bound of a quadratic form $(x,y)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}a&b \\b&c\end{pmatrix}\cdot (x,y)^t$ on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ equals the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&b \\b&c\end{pmatrix}$. Now the product of the eigenvalues is $a c - b^2$, and the their sum equals $a + c$. This might help with the problem.
